# Memory warning while downloading file with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Update:

I wrote a very simple download code:

```
NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/products/ipad/xxxx.mp4"]];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx%d.mp4",i]];
    AFDownloadRequestOperation* operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:filePath shouldResume:YES];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
    [operation setShouldOverwrite:YES];
    [operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
        NSLog(@"%f", ( totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpected));
    }];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"finished");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(error.description);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
}
```

I wrote it in my projects viewDidLoad commenting out all other codes. Memory usage is still the same and increasing:

[image]

I created a new project, and I wrote exactly the same code in the new project. And the memory usage is:

[image]

Which is good. But I don't understand why it is different in the real project?

Comment: How many cells do you in your collection view? If you have a bunch of cells that are all doing this operation, things could get hairy fast.

Comment: 10 cells doing this. What I want is, when a download finishes, closing the outputstream and releasing the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awkward. I created a new project, and copy the same code, and it is working without memory warning. Download operation doesn't effect the memory. I didn't understand the problem. Maybe because of the project settings.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you open the zombie mode.
Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
Uncheck the opition [Enable Zombie Object]

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to provide information in the form of an answer. Not sure how to parse what you've written here.

Comment: What I mean is that cancel the option which named enable Zombie Objects

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Disable zombies object worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try downloading manually by using NSOperationQueue

[Get here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi. I already used [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:_downloadOperation] in my code. What do you mean?